# flutter - background listener of MethodChannel

Tags: flutter, dart

My app sends file to ftp server. I am sending file with java on android via MethodChannel.

These parts are okay for doing all the stuff in single thread. But I would like to send file with AsyncTask (java) and background.

Also I need to send result of file upload result to Flutter with MethodChannel.

How can I do that?
I tried to user MethodChannel.Result on AsyncTask's doInBackground but it gaves me this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: AsyncTask #2
```

Comment: Hello! Having same issue here. Any solution?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply, I updated my question. @user8773560

Comment: This appears like your are using AsyncTask... Since AsyncTask are executed in another thread and your Flutter app on the main one, you can not acces `MethodChannel`. Please provide code where your are sending back response to Flutter. Then  i can provide a working solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for solving bug of '@UiThread must be executed on the main thread.'

I used this,

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   //call the methodChannel.invokeMethod here to avoid @UiThread exception
  }
 });
```

Also I implemented a new MethodChannel and a background class for communicating with native at background for always.

```
class NativeBackground {
 final methodChannel = MethodChannel('your.apps.channel/background');

 static NativeBackground _instance;
 factory NativeBackground() => _instance ? ? = NativeBackground._();
 NativeBackground._() {
  handlePlatformChannelMethods();
 }

 Future <void> handlePlatformChannelMethods() async {
  methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler((methodCall) {
   print('NativeChanell background...');
   print(methodCall.method + '(' + methodCall.arguments + ')');
  });
 }
}
```

You can use that NativeBackground class on your app's first build() method to init.

Comment: it is not a bug, it's an expected error when trying to touch a view outside the main thread

Answer (score 1):

Method channels communication must happen on UI thread. See the [official recommendation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#jumping-to-the-ui-thread-in-android) on how to do it.